# Powershell > File not found

Tags: powershell

The file is present but Powershell keeps saying file is missing. I have no idea. I looked at the permissions and current user has full rights.

```
$csvDocLib = "C:\\PowerShell\TestLib.csv"
$csvDocSet = "C:\\PowerShell\TestDocSet.csv"
```

the first csv is found and code works but down the code line i need the second csv and it said not found but it's in same directory. I tried renaming and still the same.

```
if([IO.File]::Exists($csvDocSet) -ne $false)
{  
    write-host $csvDocSet " not found" 
    exit
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate the double `\\` e.g.:

```
$csvDocLib = "C:\\PowerShell\TestLib.csv"
$csvDocSet = "C:\\PowerShell\TestDocSet.csv"
```

should be:

```
$csvDocLib = "C:\PowerShell\TestLib.csv"
$csvDocSet = "C:\PowerShell\TestDocSet.csv"
```

Comment: That did not help. I get this error Import-Csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is invalid. Change the value of the "name" ar
gument and run the operation again.
At C:\PowerShell\DocSet.ps1:49 char:26
+     foreach($j in Import-CSV <<<<  $csvDocSet)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand

Comment: OK asking the obvious, you're sure the variable contains the path you think it does & that path does really exist.  :-)  Also, rather than use [IO.File]::Exists, you can use the `Test-Path` cmdlet instead e.g. `if (!(Test-Path $csvDocSet)) { "$csvDocSet not found" }`

Comment: Perhaps you could include a bit more of your script where the error occurs and also list the error in the question where you can format it better.  What is odd here is that Import-Csv doesn't have a `Name` parameter AFAICT.  Is there a name field in the CSV file?

Comment: I created the csv with excel and now it's working. I think I had a bad csv. thanks for your help keith.